# Stuck screw in subpanel neutral bus

Tags: electrical-panel

It appears that I need to add one more neutral to the neutral bus. There is one unused screw on the bus but the screw is stuck. Any suggestions on how to loosen it up would be helpful. Do electricians have special tools to address this problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's stuck?  Or is it one of the screws which bolts the neutral bus to the panel?

Comment: What make and model is the panel in question?

Comment: Westinghouse 200 A Max type 1 enclosed  (I've no clue how much info you need)

Comment: You should be able to double up with a wire in one of the other screw fasteners in the neutral bus. But loosening a screw would disconnect that neutral. Before doing that you want to turn off the breaker to that circuit. It can be hard to find which neutral goes with which hot so you could turn off the master breaker.

Comment: @JimStewart -- no, you can't double lug a neutral like that

Comment: @continuallyfrustrated -- do you have an actual part number from the label for me, or better yet, clear photos of the labeling on the unit?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I found that the neutral bar in my GE panel didn't make reliable contact with the #12 aluminum conductor in my 15-A branch circuits. The heads of the screws would hit before the ends of the screws would fully  compress the #12 Al. Over time the neutral connection could develop resistance and heat up.  In another house in my tract neighborhood I found I could not tighten any of the screws holding #12 Al. I think the heads of the screws were not allowing tightening. I thought about trying to slip a small piece of #14 copper in the holes with the #12 Al, but you don't approve?!

Comment: Would it be allowed to connect two #14 neutrals to a pigtail #10 and have the pigtail in the neutral bar? (Or connect two #12 neutrals to a #8 pigtail which connects at the neutral bar?) In my case 35 years ago I individually pigtailed all the neutrals in my panel with #12 Cu.

Comment: @JimStewart -- pigtailing the neutrals with a connector approved for the application would be the fix indeed :) (and yes, using a 3 or 4 hole connector would let you multiplex multiple neutrals onto a single pigtail, minding ampacity of course)

Answer (score 2):

Forget about the stuck screw. Go to another point in the neutral bar and remove an existing neutral. Using an appropriate wire nut or other connector connect the existing neutral with the new neutral and with a pigtail of size to carry current from both neutrals. Insert the other end of the pigtail into the neutral bar.

Before disconnecting or even loosening any neutral, turn off the breaker for that circuit.

Comment: Just make sure that the neutral jumper is of sufficient size for the addition. I would think a small piece of #8 or maybe a #6  would do, but just a WAG (wild ass guess). We need to know how many neutrals you would be connecting along with amperage and purpose.

Comment: #10 would do for two #14s and #8 for two #12s. Not sure if any wire of larger than #8 would fit in the smallest holes in the neutral bar. Would even #8 fit? I'd expect that #10 would.

Comment: Yep. You would need to do a calculation before expanding too much. I tell you what you could do if the bus has neutrals and grounds. You separate the ground wires from the neutral and use the extra bus to install the grounds. Then add the new neutrals to the original bus. Then your extra bus would only need to be sized to the largest ground on the bus. Minimum #10.

Comment: Retired Master Electrician, just to make sure I understand, I have 20 amp circuits on 12 gauge wire. You and Jim are suggesting I wire nut two of the neutrals with a pigtail of a fatter wire and connect the fat wire to the neutral bus. Right? The biggest wire I have on hand is #8; will that be enough or should I get a piece of #6 to do it?

Comment: Yes. #8 wire is rated for 40 A which would carry the maximum current from two 20-A neutrals.

Comment: You would use a grey wire nut for the connection of two #12s and one #8.

Comment: What did you end up doing?